# How to speed up viewing heic-images on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I use XnView to view heic images. The images come from my smartphone and are from 1 to 5 Mb, it takes up to 3-4 seconds to open a single image which is much slower than opening a jpeg image of the same size with the same XnView. Is there a way to speed up the process? Another image viewer or another plugin for XnView maybe? Would a new CPU help (mine is an i3 4th gen.).